# Create the proper URL Rewrite on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been trying this for a few days and cant make it to work.
I have this structure:

http://blablabla.com/pel/es/whatever

But I want it to show as:

http://blablabla.com/es/whatever

The first is a real folder, and it needs to be like that. But for SEM and SEO, I really need it to show without the "pel" in between. I read a lot of documentation on how to do the oposite, or about how to hide variables etc...  but I couldnt find anything talking about my case exactly, closest was to hide all folders from URL. I tried all posibilities I could come up with with no success. It seems prety obvious, but I just cant make it work. I tried using the .htacccess on the root and also inside that "pel/es/" folder... It´s just no use. My last try was, puting this on the .htaccess on inside the /pel/es/ folder:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pel/$
   RewriteRule ^es/$ pel/es/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can anyboy help please?

Tino

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have the `es` folder inside `/pel`, or does the entire site reside in the `/pel` folder?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# rewrite to pel folder
RewriteCond $0 !^pel/
RewriteRule .* /pel/$0 [L]

# if you only want to rewrite the /es folder use this
#RewriteRule es/.* /pel/$0 [L]


# Remove /pel/ from the address bar
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule pel/(.*) /$1 [L,R=302]
#change to 301 once you get it working
```

Comment: @Gerben.Thanx, but no success. I should have explain better. We are using Magento and for technical issues (to difference between storeviews, long story..) we must have that folder structure, "root/pel/es/", but inside that folder, there is only an .htaccess and an index.php, where I state the proper storeview. So I just dnt know where should I put this. on the root or on the folder...

Comment: First you say it doesn't work, and then you say you don't know where to put it. Please try, or explain what you tried, before asking for more help.